# why Border radious is not supporting to chrome and IE10. can you give any solution please

Tags: css, stylesheet

why Border radious  is not supporting to chrome and IE10. can you give any solution please my code

```
/* Rounded Corner */
.tb5 {

    border-radius:10px;
    height: 18px;
    width: 230px;
     border: 3px solid #BADA55;

     /* Safari 3-4, iOS 1-3.2, Android 1.6- */
  -webkit-border-radius: 12px; 

  /* Firefox 1-3.6 */
  -moz-border-radius: 12px; 

  /* Opera 10.5, IE 9, Safari 5, Chrome, Firefox 4, iOS 4, Android 2.1+ */
  border-radius: 12px; 

}
```

Comment: Seems to render fine for me in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/73bnV/

Answer (score 2):

Should work fine in the latest version of every browser, even without prefixes ([source](http://caniuse.com/border-radius)). Are you sure you're targetting the right HTML element?

```
<div class="tb5">
    <p>Something here...</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with `-ms-border-radius:12px;`

Comment: The `border-radius` rule has been standardized in the most recent browsers. http://caniuse.com/border-radius